# How to Add the installation prefix of "Qt5QmlModels" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH

Tags: 20.04, compiling, application-development

```
CMake Error at /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/cmake/Qt5/Qt5Config.cmake:28 (find_package):
  Could not find a package configuration file provided by "Qt5QmlModels" with
  any of the following names:

    Qt5QmlModelsConfig.cmake
    qt5qmlmodels-config.cmake

  Add the installation prefix of "Qt5QmlModels" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or set
  "Qt5QmlModels_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above files.  If
  "Qt5QmlModels" provides a separate development package or SDK, be sure it
  has been installed.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:621 (find_package)


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/home/Parveen_Linphone/linphone-sdk/build/WORK/desktop/Build/ms2/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
```

Comment: What is your Ubuntu version?

Comment: its ubuntu 20.04

Comment: What is your final idea? Why do you need to compile an application which is packaged?

Comment: i need to make some changes to the SDP for my project and hence need to compile and build the app

Comment: Then you can try to adapt a version which is supported by the libs inside 20.04 LTS - see  https://packages.ubuntu.com/source/focal/linphone . If you want to walk this way, I'll update my answer.

Answer (score 1):

For modern Ubuntu system (21.04 and newer) you have to install the [corresponding package](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=hirsute&arch=amd64&mode=filename&searchon=contents&keywords=Qt5QmlModelsConfig) by

```
sudo apt-get install qtdeclarative5-dev
```

Also it should be noted that Linphone is packaged for Ubuntu, see [search results at packages.ubuntu.com](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=all&searchon=sourcenames&keywords=linphone).

Comment: it is already installed ..
osboxes@osboxes:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/cmake$ sudo apt-get install qtdeclarative5-dev
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
qtdeclarative5-dev is already the newest version (5.12.8-0ubuntu1).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 21 not upgraded.
osboxes@osboxes:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/cmake$